# Loosly coupled ui written in javascript and hosted on port 8080, how do I communicate using json to my java application running on port 80

Tags: java, angularjs, cross-domain, jsonp, jackson

This is largely a new area for me, so my question is more on helpful resources.

I have an apache server running on port 80 that simply hosts a javascript application.

This java application gets its data through rest calls made to a java application running in jetty on port 8080.

For the front end I am using AngularJS. My request service looks like this:

```
(function(ng, app){
    "use strict";
    app.service(
    "questService",
    function( $q, $http, _, categoryService ) {
        function($q, _, $http){
            function getQuestsFromServer(){
                $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/worldcraft/quests'}).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("SUCESS!! {status: " + status + " \nData:" + data + "}");
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("FAILURE!! {status: " + status + " \nData:" + data + "}");
                });             
            }
        }
        return getQuestsFromServer : getQuestsFromServer;
    })
})(angular, Worldcraft);
```

in the java application I have a service like this

```
@Singleton
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("worldcraft/quests")
public class QuestbookService {

    private Questbook questbook;

    @Inject
    public QuestbookService(Questbook questBook) {
        this.questbook = questBook;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Quest> getQuests() {
        return questbook.getQuests();
    }

}
```

When using chrome to test this, I get the javascript exception: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.myserver.com:8080/worldcraft/quests. Origin http://www.myserver.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

After doing research, it seems the correct solution is using JSONP. But I haven't seen anything online that really helps me understand how to do this with the technology I Have in place.

The java stack is using jetty, jackson, jersy, with guice to facade the servlets.

The front end stack is using AngularJS to do the routing.

The AngularJS platform is hosted on port 80 with a regular Apache server.

any advice or tips would be nice, research topics would be preferred. Or an explanation of what I may be doing wrong.

Comment: _"not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"_ seems to indicate your Java service has sent an anti-cross-site-scripting header.

Comment: First of all, do you really need them to be in different servers? If not, then put them in the same one and everything will work

Comment: the goal is to have the front end completely separate and host able by other people than my java application. The cross site is crucial. @JimGarrison do you know of any good area of documentation to help me understand how to correct the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java application running on port 80 must write a specific header to its response stream:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Since you have 'static' content hosted on your :80 site, you will have to ask Apache to add this header via mod_headers. Create a .htaccess file in the root directory with this content:

```
<filesmatch ".*">
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</filesmatch>
```

Where the parameter defines Caller URIs individually separated by the pipe (|) sign, or * as wildcard.

The reason you're getting this error is because the browser implements the 'same origin policy'.

This change needs to be implemented on your **source** application.

You can read the [header reference here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Comment: I do not have a java application running on port 80. Its a pure javascript application running on port 80 hosted by Apache 2.2.17. The java application is a pure server side rest server hosted on port 8080 using the jetty imbedded server. With that said, which server needs to correct the xsite header? The html5 app server or the java server app? Or is this something configurable in javascript right in the browser using angular.

Comment: Oh, my bad - I misread your question. You may ask Apache to add the header via a .htaccess file. I'll adjust my answer accordingly. Unfortunately you won't be able to implement this directly via javascript.

Comment: Thank you very very much! I really appricate the help.